# Need to know weird behavior of angular and rails applicaiton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am working on an application developed in angular on front end and rails on back-end. I have just faced a weird problem. I have an angular url defined in `app.js`

```
when('scorecard/currentscore', {
  templateUrl: 'scorecard/card.html',
  controller: 'ScorecardController'
})
```

And in `scorecard/card.html`, the previous developer had to use date so he changed filename from `scorecard/card.html` to `scorecard/card.html.erb` and used date like   `<%= Date.current.strftime("%B") %>`. It generates no error but it shows weird behavior.

Like first time when feature was deployed it was March. So first time the file was accessed on March. So in browser it shows `March`. So now even if it is `May` it is still showing `March`. I just put one space in that file, refreshed browser and it started showing current month. I have verified this issue on multiple systems. Until you made a simple change in the file, it keeps on showing the previously visited date. First time I have tested this in April. It was showing March. I put one space and it started showing April. And when even May started, it keep on showing April. I have again put some space and some text and it showed May.

Similarly I have an angular controller. I needed to access a `ruby constant` defined in `constants.rb` file. I changed my controller extension and put `.erb` after `.js.` So until I change that file, it only shows previously visited value of that constant. That constant is actually a date array which should be automatically updated on each day.

Can any body tell me what is this behavior?

Comment: Not specialist on ror, but as you explained it, it seems the server ask the browser to cache the erb template based on its content. I would try to open the dev console in your browser and look for the http `Cache-control` header. If this is it, then you have to configure your server to avoid sending cache request for this template.

Comment: It's true this is a caching issue, but it's occurring server-side via the asset pipeline, and is not related to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `scorecard/card.html` is somewhere in `app/assets` and that March was the last date this specific file was edited?

If so, the issue is that you're calling Ruby code from within an asset file that isn't being compiled on each request. This is the norm for assets. For efficiency, Sprockets caches each file based on a digest of its content and won't actually evaluate any code in that file until it sees a change (or you call `rake assets:precompile` if you're running the asset pipeline). However, if you want to reset the Sprockets cache in development mode, you can run `rake tmp:clear:cache` or delete `/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/development/`

Long story short, avoid using Ruby code anywhere within your assets directory. It will most likely only get executed within the `rake assets:precompile` step (this is also the reason why certain asset gems like `sass-rails` have non-ruby asset helper methods like `image-url`, etc.).

Probably the best solution here is to either fetch the current date from the server using an AJAX request, or to simply use stick to javascript in your Angular templates.